# R Code is getting undefined columns selected error but data column is present

Tags: r, validation

Im testing some R code that I found online and would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me why I am facing this error.

I'm a newbie when it comes to R so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

The error I get is as follows.

```
    > temp <- lapply(unique(rossmann.df[!is.na(Competition_Start_Date)]$Store), beforeAndAfterComp)
Error in `[.data.frame`(rossmann.df, !is.na(Competition_Start_Date)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

My code snippet is as follows

```
    # Competition effect over time


    library(car)
    library(data.table)
    library(zoo)
    library(forecast)
    library(ggplot2)


    #Read dataset

    rossmann.df<-read.csv(paste("TrainCluster.csv", sep=""))
    View(rossmann.df)
    dim(rossmann.df)

    #Create a descriptive statistics (min, max, median etc) of each variable.
    summary(rossmann.df)

timespan <- 100 
# Days to collect before and after Opening of competition


beforeAndAfterComp <- function(s) {
  x <- rossmann.df[Store == s]
  daysWithComp <- x$CompetitionOpenSince >= x$DateYearmon
  if (any(!daysWithComp)) {
    compOpening <- head(which(!daysWithComp), 1) - 1
    if (compOpening > timespan & compOpening < (nrow(x) - timespan)) {
      x <- x[(compOpening - timespan):(compOpening + timespan), ]
      x$Day <- 1:nrow(x)
      return(x)
    }
  }
}



temp <- lapply(unique(rossmann.df[!is.na(Competition_Start_Date)]$Store), beforeAndAfterComp)
```

Why am I getting this error? I confirmed that **Competition_Start_Date is present in my data frame.**

My data columns are as follows :

"Store","StoreType","Assortment","CompetitionDistance",
  "CompetitionOpenSinceMonth","CompetitionOpenSinceYear",
  "Promo2","Promo2SinceWeek","Promo2SinceYear","nPromoInteval",
  "StoreType_Assortment","Promo2_Year_Begin","Day_Promo2_Start",
  "Date_Promo2_Start","CompetitionDistance_Impute","CompetitionOpen_Impute",
  "DayOfWeek","Date","DayofDate","MonthofDate","YearofDate","Quarter","Sales",
  "Customers","Open","Promo","StateHoliday","SchoolHoliday",
  "**Competition_Start_Date**","Day_bfat_Comp","Day_bfat_Promo2",
  "Flag_Day_bf_Comp","Flag_day_bf_Promo2","cluster"

Comment: `R#` is the shortcut for *Resharper*, a C# refactoring tool. You probably mean `R`, the statistical language

Comment: As for the error, it's pretty clear. You are trying to use column names that don't exist in your file. You haven't posted an example of your file, so it's impossible to say exactly what's wrong. What does `summary(rossman.df)` say anyway? What are the columns?

Comment: Competition_Start_Date is present in my column names, I have provided them now.

Comment: You are most likely looking for something like `lapply(unique(rossmann.df[!is.na(rossmann.df$Competition_Start_Date), ]$Store), beforeAndAfterComp)`, but it's hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Competition_Start_Date is present in the data frame, but you haven't told R to look there, so it's looking in the global environment.

```
rossman.df[!is.na(rossman.df$Competition_Start_Date)]$Store
```

is probably what you want?